# Exclude Input formControlName in form angular6

Tags: angular

I want to get the formControlName input tag value before submitting the form.
So I have created one method to get the value. But I am not able to get the current input value of formControlName.

I have removed formcontrolname to exclude from form to get ngmodel input value only but I got error that form should have formcontrolname..

```
<form [formGroup]="FormGroup1" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 ...
 <input type="text" formControlName="searchContent" [(ngModel)]="search"/>
<button  type="button" (click)=getValue(search)></button>
 ...
 </form>
```

In typescript,I have initialized like this

```
 FormGroup1: FormGroup;
    FormGroup1: FormGroup;  
     this.FormGroup1= new FormGroup({                           
       .....
      searchContent: new FormControl(),
      ...
     });
```

Without submitting the form, I need this input current value..

Comment: If you have a `formControlName` property, then you have a form group instance. And if you have a form group instance, you have access to all controls, which means you have access to all form control names.

Comment: Thanks for your reply trichetriche.. But I got searchContent, search value as 'undefined' while clicking button. I have already declared  in typescript like this                                                            
   " FormGroup1: FormGroup;  
   this.FormGroup1= new FormGroup({                           
       .....
      searchContent: new FormControl(),
      ...
    }); "

Comment: remove ngModel from input element and use valueChanges to subscribe the value

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to your control value changes this way:

```js
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

// imports and decorator

formGroup = this.fb.group({
  // other fields
  searchContent: [''],
});

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

this.formGroup.controls.searchContent.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    // do stuff
});

// Getting the value of a field
submit() {
 const searchValue = this.formGroup.controls.searchContent.value;
}
```

Use of camelCase is better for variables in typescript (formGroup instead of FormGroup)

Comment: I got  "Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined". I am using angular 7..

Comment: Can you add the initialisation of your formGroup in your question ?

Comment: I edited my answer consequently, and added a simple form initialization you can try :)
It seems like there is a problem with your context, the formGroup is probably not found in your this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
this.formGroup1.controls.get['searchContent'].valueChanges.subscribe(va‌​lue => {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: I got "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'AbstractControl' has no compatible call signatures" in typescript

Comment: @Deepa Replace '()' by '[]'.I have edited the code.Please try

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to watch for input changes and just want to fetch the value at a certain point, i.e. before form submission, you can use a Template Variable.

```
<form [formGroup]="FormGroup1" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 ...
 <input #searchInput type="text" formControlName="searchContent" [(ngModel)]="search"/>
 <button  type="button" (click)=getValue(searchInput)></button>
 ...
</form>


@Component()
class MyComponent{
  getValue(searchInput) {
    console.log(searchInput.nativeElement.value);
  }
}
```

This is the simplest solution, you can also use @ViewChild() if you don't want to pass the searchInput from your template to your component's code.

Just using `formControlName` stuff, your code should look like this:

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="FormGroup1" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 ...
 <input type="text" formControlName="searchContent">
 <button  type="button" (click)=getSearchValue()></button>
 ...
</form>
```

TYPESCRIPT:

```
class MyComponent {
   FormGroup1: FormGroup;  
   constructor() {
     this.FormGroup1 = new FormGroup({
       searchContent: new FormControl('')
     }); 
   }

   getSearchValue() {
     console.log(this.FormGroup1.get('searchContent').value);
   }
}
```

Also, just make sure you have `ReactiveFormsModule` imported in the module this component is declared in.

Comment: I got "Cannot read property 'searchContent' of undefined". I have added ReactiveFormsModule.

Comment: @Deepa can you please add your code to your question where you're trying to access the value?

Answer (score 0):

I included another form within form,

```
<form [formGroup]="FormGroup1" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 ...
<div [formGroup]="searchFormGroup">
 <input type="text" formControlName="searchContent" [(ngModel)]="search"/>
<button  type="button" (click)=getValue(search)></button>
</div>
 ...
 </form>
```

Declared in typescript

```
this.searchFormGroup = new FormGroup({ searchContent: new FormControl()});
```

And I removed searchContent variable in formGroup1.. Now its working..